# Bootstrap3 tabs in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-class-based-views

I want to implement [Bootstrap3 tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) in my app, which displays school data by state. So if you go to example.com/ma/ you will see information for the state of Massachusetts and tabs to sort by grade level.

I am already using the queryset to filter by state so that on example.com/ma/ only "ma" results appear. And I can show ALL data in one of the tabs, but can't filter it out for multiple tabs. To keep it simple, I just want to do tabs for "All" and "High School" here.

Here is my *models.py*:
    from django.db import models

```
class School(models.Model):
    school_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location_state  = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    grades = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Here is my template for *state.py*:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{ state }}</h2> #This works and shows the state based on the URL

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#all">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="#high">High School</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

{% for school in schools_by_state %}
<div id="content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ school.school_name }}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="high">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ ???highschool??? }}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>  
</div><!-- end content -->
</div><!-- end row -->
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

And here is my *views.py*:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .models import School

class StateListView(ListView):
    model = School
    template_name = 'state.html'
    context_object_name = 'schools_by_state'

    def get_queryset(self):
        state_list = self.kwargs['location_state']
        return School.objects.filter(location_state=state_list)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StateListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update({'state': self.kwargs['location_state']})
        return context
```

For completeness, here is the *urls.py* for this view:

```
url(r'^(?P<location_state>[A-Z]{2})/$', StateListView.as_view()),
```

I don't believe I want to use multiple querysets here, but instead find a way to add an additional filter to my context_data in the view for "highschool" which I can then add to my template. However my attempts to add additional context filters have all failed. Thoughts?

Comment: So you want to have two tabs, one that shows all schools for that state, and one that shows a subset of schools? What is the subset?

Comment: Do you want one tab for EACH highschool, or one tab for ALL highschools in one state?

Comment: @jproffitt Yes, correct. The subset for the second tab is for High School, so in the model that is where the field "grades" = "9-12".

Comment: @Jay One tab for ALL highschools in one state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add a new queryset to the context:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(StateListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context.update({'state': self.kwargs['location_state']})

    context['schools_highschool'] = context['schools_by_state'].filter(grades='9-12')

    return context
```

Then loop `schools_highschool` in the template. I think your template is a little off too. Maybe do this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h2>{{ state }}</h2> #This works and shows the state based on the URL

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
            <li class="active"><a href="#all">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#high">High School</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>


    <div id="content" class="tab-content">

        <div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
            <ul>
                {% for school in schools_by_state %}
                    <li>{{ school.school_name }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tab-pane" id="high">
            <ul>
                {% for school in schools_highschool %}
                    <li>{{ school.school_name }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>  

    </div><!-- end content -->

</div><!-- end row -->

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You just rocked my world. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

jproffitts answer is correct, but you can also filter based on this one query set in your template:

```
<div id="content" class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="all">
    <ul>
        {% for school in schools_by_state %}
        <li>{{ school.school_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="high">
    <ul>
        {% for school in schools_by_state %}
         {% if school.grade == "9-12" %}
        <li>{{ school.school_name }}</li>
         {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </div>  
</div><!-- end content -->
```

Comment: Thank you for this example. I've read elsewhere (largely in 2 Scoops of Django) that filtering in Views is better from a performance point of view than in Templates. Would you agree with that?