# Bootstrap 3 Tabs and Django Forms

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I'm building something similar to the tabbed structure in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846967/bootstrap3-tabs-in-django). I have a set of students, and I want tabs inside a modal that pull up a form to allow me to select some of them to be members of the Section object.

I have the tabs, and have a form that filters by grade, but I can't get the grade variable into the form to provide the filtering when I click the tab. If I were reloading the page, I could figure that out, or even if I created 15 different forms (one for each grade), and called them separately, but that seems like an awful way to do it.

How do I render the form upon tab switching, while passing the name of the tab (the grade) to the form? Everything works perfectly, as long as I hard-code the grade info into the form.

forms.py

```
class RosterAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = ['students']
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        details = kwargs.pop('details',None)
        this_section = details['this_section']
        roster = this_section.students.all()
        super(RosterAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['students'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        try:
            self.fields['students'].queryset = Student.objects.filter(Grade="11")
```

## this hard-coding is the issue: need this to be via selected tab

```
            self.fields['students'].initial = roster
        except:
            pass
```

views.py

```
...
        details = {'this_section':this_section, 'roster':roster}
        rosteraddform = RosterAddForm(None,prefix='rosteradd',details=details)

        context = {'this_teacher':this_teacher,'coursezip':coursezip,'this_course':this_course,
                    'this_section':this_section, 'this_admin':this_admin, 'adminzip':adminzip,
                    'roster':roster, 'rosteraddform':rosteraddform, 'grades':["3-4","PK","K","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"],
                  }

        return render(request,'benchmarks/teacherindex.html', context)

    elif request.method == "POST":

        this_section = Section.objects.get(pk=Section_id)
        roster = this_section.students.all()

        details = {'this_section':this_section, 'roster':roster}
        rosteraddform = RosterAddForm(request.POST,prefix='rosteradd',details=details)

        if rosteraddform.is_valid():
            #a list of the pk's of chosen students
            chosen_students = rosteraddform.cleaned_data['students']
            this_section.students.clear()
            for kid in chosen_students:
                this_section.students.add(kid)

            return redirect(reverse('benchmarks:indexteacher', kwargs={'Section_id':Section_id,'Teacher_id':Teacher_id}))
        else:
            return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

html

```
!-- Roster add modal -->

<div class="modal fade" id="RosterAddModal" role="dialog" >
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width:900px;">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:5px 10px;">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4>Add to Roster</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:10px 10px;">
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" >
      {% for grade in grades %}
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#{{ grade }}" aria-controls={{ grade }} role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{ grade }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content" style="background:#EEEEEE; max-height:1000px; min-height:400px;" >

    {% for grade in grades %}
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane " id="{{ grade }}" style="padding:15px;">
      {{ grade }}
    <form data-parsley-validate method="post" id="rosteraddform" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                data-parsley-trigger="focusout">

        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ rosteraddform.as_p }}


        <p id="login-error"></p>

        <input type="submit" class="btn submit" name="RosterAdd" value="Add Students" />
      </form>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here, which isn't perfect, was to render each version of the form ahead of time:

```
details = {'this_section':this_section, 'roster':roster}

    grades = ["3-4","PK","K","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
    rosteraddforms = []
    for grade in grades:
        rosteraddforms.append(RosterAddForm(None,prefix='rosteradd'+grade,details=details,grade=grade))
    gradezip = zip(grades,rosteraddforms)
```

In the template, iterate through the zip when creating the tabs.

In the view for the `POST`:

```
if any(key.startswith("RosterAdd") for key in request.POST):
        print "roster add"
        this_section = Section.objects.get(pk=Section_id)
        roster = this_section.students.all()

        details = {'this_section':this_section, 'roster':roster}
        rosteraddforms = []
        grades = ["3-4","PK","K","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12"]
        for grade in grades:
            rosteraddforms.append(RosterAddForm(request.POST, prefix = 'rosteradd'+grade,details=details))
        #print request.POST

        for rosteraddform in rosteraddforms:
            grade = rosteraddform.prefix[9:]

            if 'RosterAdd'+grade in request.POST:
                rosteraddformused = rosteraddform
                if rosteraddform.is_valid():
```